# Removing object in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

If I had an `ArrayList` with two objects which are the same,  and I used `remove` in this `ArrayList`, which one would be removed?

For example:

```
People p=new people();
ArrayList<People> peoples = new ArrayList<>();

peoples.add(p);
peoples.add(p);
peoples.remove(p);
```

Comment: Why don't you read the doc of remove?

Comment: Check in api document.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being lazy about reading the documentation.

Comment: how does it matter anyway which got removed, at the end you have one p and both were equal. :-)

Comment: the situation of that object in array list is important for me @Panther

Comment: its just one object p which you are avoiding or you don't want duplicates at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are avoiding the duplicates, then you can use this approach .

```
People p=new people();
ArrayList<People> peoples = new ArrayList<>();


if(!peoples.contains(p)){
peoples.add(p);
}

if(!peoples.contains(p)){
peoples.add(p);
}
```

you can check with .contains before adding to list.
And if you are not creating this list in your code, i mean getting from some other api or method on which you don't have control. Then create new in your method and move each element from first list to your list, by checking contains

Answer (score 2):

It'll remove the first one.

Note that it's slightly more complicated than this, though. In your example, you have added the same instance `p` twice. But if you add `p` and then `q`, and they're equal in the sense that `p.equals(q)`, then an attempt to remove `q` will remove `p` instead (because it comes before it, and is equal to it).

To remove the last one, you need

```
peoples.remove(peoples.lastIndexOf(p));
```

Comment: if I want to remove a list of these last index what should i do? I mean that in the for I want to remove 5 object of these last index and if i delete them in the for i will get an exception

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) it says:

`Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present.`

To delete the last one:

```
peoples.remove(peoples.lastIndexOf(p));
```

Comment: if I want to delete last one,what should i do?

Comment: @user3813380 why would it matter? it's the same object... but if you really have to, you can loop it

Comment: A loop is unnecessary here. It's enough to get the last occurrence of the object and then call remove(int index). `peoples.remove(peoples.lastIndexOf(p))`

Comment: because the situation of that object  in array list is important for me

Comment: @Sal lastIndexOf will remove the instance of p even if it is only one in list and what about scenraio he has more than 2 in list and he wants only one